# good practices in django authentication system

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a question, when adding the authentication urls of the `auth` application (`django.contrib.auth.urls`).

Where should I add the templates? (`login.html`, etc)

I have seen that they add in the `templates` folder of the project:

```
project > templates > registration > login.html ...
```

I've also seen that they do it in an application called `registration`:

```
|-- project
    |-- registration
        |-- templates
        |   |-- registration
        |       |-- login.html
        |           ....
        |
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- admin.py
            .....
```

But that name doesn't convince me much, I've also seen that they do it in applications called `users` and`accounts`

In which app should I do it? (`accounts`, `users`, `registration`)

which one is best practice?

I also want to comment that I am creating a custom user model, and I think it should go in one of these apps right? It would be the most logical, according to the name of the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom user app then you can put the account templates in project/your_user_app/templates/registration. In this case your_user_app would need to be right at the top of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'your_user_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
     ...  
     ...
]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_user_app.your_custom_user_model'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
         ...
    },
]
```

OR you can put the account templates in project/templates/registration and edit the DIRS in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...

        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],

        ...
    },
]
```

The second option also works if you don't have a custom user app but just want to customise the templates.

Comment: What do you think about putting the custom user model in the `core` app?